# Php административная панель сайта

Tags: javascript, php, html

Всем,привет)
Есть сайт, у сайта есть несколько админок(главная и админки городов). Необходимо сделать запрет входа на админку другого города для админов других городов. Например, из города Москвы можно запросто перейти в СПБ(вбив в адресной строке файл СПБ)
  Заранее спасибо)

Comment: Каждому админу города присвойте индивидуальный айдишник и допуск к админке только по сравнению id

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете получать город по геолокации, например, через яндекс, используя библиотеку, и сохранить в куки:

```js
<script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0-stable/?load=package.standard&lang=en-EN" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
    window.onload = function() { // При загрузке страницы...
        let City = ymaps.geolocation.city; // Поолучаем город геолокации
        document.cookie = 'City='+City; // сохраняем в куки
    }
</script>
```

Далее через файл `php` получаете куки, и используете его либо добавляя в сессию, либо прям из куки для валидации при входе на конкретную страницу:

```php
<?php
$City = $_COOKIE['City']; // получаем куки
echo 'Ваш город - '.$City;
if($City != 'Moscow'){
    echo 'Вы не имеете доступа к этой странице';
} else {
    //Код страницы
}
```